# unmute-mute and stop video in videocall

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc, peerjs

This code is not working as the video audio muted on the user1 screen but on the next user2 screen it's unable to stop. The same problem is with the mic. Please help me out.
I tried it out on the localhost only. Please tell if this problem occurs on localhost only or will occur in deployed web applications also.

```
const socket = io("/");
const chatInputBox = document.getElementById("chat_message");
const all_messages = document.getElementById("all_messages");
const main__chat__window = document.getElementById("main__chat__window");
const videotable = document.getElementById("video-table");
const myVideo = document.createElement("video");
myVideo.muted = true;//for not recieving own voice

var peer = new Peer(undefined, {
  path: "/peerjs",
  host: "/",
  port: "3000",
});

let myVideoStream;
const peers = {};
var getUserMedia =
  navigator.getUserMedia ||
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
  navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

//setting initial controls of video and passing them as constraints
const constraints = {
      'video': true,
      'audio': true
}
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then((stream) => {
    myVideoStream = stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo,myVideoStream);//call to function addVideoStream
    //answering to calls
    peer.on("call", (call) => {
      call.answer(myVideoStream);
      const video = document.createElement("video");

      call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);// Show stream in some video/canvas element.
      });
    });

    socket.on("user_connected", (userId) => {//recieving info
      connectToNewUser(userId, stream);//call function with id and stream
    });
    //adding event for messages of chat
    document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
      if (e.which === 13 && chatInputBox.value != "") {
        socket.emit("message", chatInputBox.value);
        chatInputBox.value = "";
      }
    });
    //adding text to chat window
    socket.on("createMessage", (msg) => {
      //console.log(msg);
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = msg;
      all_messages.append(li);
      main__chat__window.scrollTop = main__chat__window.scrollHeight;//scrolled to latest message
    });
  });
//For disconnecting user
socket.on('user_disconnected', userId => {
  if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close()
});

peer.on("call", function (call) {
  getUserMedia(constraints,
    function (stream) {
      call.answer(stream); // Answer the call with an A/V stream.
      const video = document.createElement("video");
      call.on("stream", function (remoteStream) {
        addVideoStream(video, remoteStream); // Show stream in some video/canvas element.
      });
    },
    function (err) {
      console.log("Failed to get local stream", err);
    }
  );
});

peer.on("open", (id) => {//send with an id for user
  // on open will be launch when you successfully connect to PeerServ
  socket.emit("join_room", ROOM_ID, id);//emiting event
});

// Fetch an array of devices of a certain type
async function getConnectedDevices(type) {
    const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
    return devices.filter(device => device.kind === type)
}

// Open camera with echoCancellation for better audio
async function openCamera(cameraId) {
    const constraints = {
        'audio': {'echoCancellation': true}
        }
    return await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
}

const cameras = getConnectedDevices('videoinput');
if (cameras && cameras.length > 0) {
    const stream = openCamera(cameras[0].deviceId);
}

function connectToNewUser (userId, streams) {
  const call = peer.call(userId, streams);
  //console.log(call);
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
    //console.log(userVideoStream);
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
  });
  call.on('close', () => {
   video.remove()//for removing video elemnt on closing call
 });
 peers[userId] = call;
};

const addVideoStream = (videoEl, stream) => {
  videoEl.srcObject = stream;
  videoEl.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    videoEl.play();
  });

  videotable.append(videoEl);//adding video to front-end
  let totalUsers = document.getElementsByTagName("video").length;
  if (totalUsers > 1) {
    for (let index = 0; index < totalUsers; index++) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("video")[index].style.width =
        100 / totalUsers + "%";
    }
  }
};

//js for pause and play of video
const playStop = () => {
  let enabled = myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled;
  if (enabled) {
    myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;
    setPlayVideo();
  } else {
    myVideoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true;
    setStopVideo();
  }
};

//js of pause and play of audio
const muteUnmute = () => {
  let enabled = myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled;
  if (enabled) {
    myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
    setUnmuteButton();
  } else {
    myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true;
    setMuteButton();
  }
};

//setting icon for representing current state of video
const setPlayVideo = () => {
  const html = `<i class="unmute fa fa-pause-circle"></i>
  <span class="unmute">Resume Video</span>`;
  document.getElementById("playPauseVideo").innerHTML = html;
};

//setting icon for representing current state of video
const setStopVideo = () => {
  const html = `<i class=" fa fa-video-camera"></i>
  <span class="">Pause Video</span>`;
  document.getElementById("playPauseVideo").innerHTML = html;
};

//setting icon for representing current state of audio
const setUnmuteButton = () => {
  const html = `<i class="unmute fa fa-microphone-slash"></i>
  <span class="unmute">Unmute</span>`;
  document.getElementById("muteButton").innerHTML = html;
};
//setting icon for representing current state of audio
const setMuteButton = () => {
  const html = `<i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>
  <span>Mute</span>`;
  document.getElementById("muteButton").innerHTML = html;
};
```

This code is not working as the video audio muted on the user1 screen but on the next user2 screen it's unable to stop. The same problem is with the mic. Please help me out.
I tried it out on the localhost only. Please tell if this problem occurs on localhost only or will occur in deployed web applications also.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending server the request to stop the video call for all members in the room as client don't have control for every one then server will send request to all clients to stop the video.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    forceNew: true,
    transports: ["polling"],
})
const { ExpressPeerServer } = require('peer');
const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
    debug: true
});
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid')

app.use('/peerjs', peerServer);

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`)
})

app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
    res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room })
})

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
        socket.join(roomId)
        socket.to(roomId).emit('user-connected', userId)
        socket.on('message', message => {
            io.to(roomId).emit('createMessage',message) 
        })
        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            socket.to(roomId).emit('user-disconnected', userId)
        })
        socket.on('toggle-video', data => {
            socket.broadcast.emit('toggle-video', data);
        })
        socket.on('toggle-audio', data => {
            socket.broadcast.emit('toggle-audio', data);
        })
    })
})

server.listen(3000)
```

this is my server.js file

```
    const socket = io('/')
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')
const peer = new Peer(undefined, {
    path: '/peerjs',
    host: '/',
    port: '3000',
})
let myVideoStream;
let audio = true;

const myVideo = document.createElement('video')
myVideo.muted = true
const peers = {}
var getUserMedia =
    navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
}).then(stream => {
    myVideoStream = stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream)

    socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
        connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
    })
    let text = $('input')

    $('html').keydown((e) => {
        if (e.which == 13 && text.val().length !== 0) {
            console.log(text.val());
            socket.emit('message', { user: peer.id, message: text.val() });
            text.val('')
        }
    })

    socket.on('toggle-video', data => {
        const userId = data.userId;
        const videoEnabled = data.videoEnabled;
    
        const videoElement = document.getElementById(userId);
    
        if (videoElement) {
            if (videoEnabled) {
                videoElement.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                videoElement.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    });

    socket.on('toggle-audio', data => {
        const userId = data.userId;
        const audioEnabled = data.audioEnabled;
    
        const audioElement = document.getElementById(userId);
    
        if (audioElement) {
            if (audioEnabled) {
                audioElement.muted = true;
            } else {
                audioElement.muted = false;
            }
        }
    });

    socket.on('createMessage', message => {
        $('.messages').append(`<li class="message"><b>${message.user}</b><br/>${message.message}</li>`)
        scrollToBottom()
    })

})

peer.on("call", call => {
    getUserMedia(
        { video: true, audio: true },
        stream => {
            call.answer(stream); // Answer the call with an A/V stream.
            const video = document.createElement("video")
            video.setAttribute('id', `${call.metadata.senderUserId}`)
            call.on("stream", function (remoteStream) {
                addVideoStream(video, remoteStream);
            })
            call.on('close', () => {
                video.remove()
            })
            peers[call.metadata.senderUserId] = call
        },
        err => {
            console.log("Failed to get local stream", err);
        }
    );
});

socket.on('user-disconnected', userId => {
    if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close()
})

peer.on('open', id => {
    socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id)
})

function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
    const call = peer.call(userId, stream, { metadata: { senderUserId: peer.id } })
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    video.setAttribute('id', `${userId}`)
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
    })
    call.on('close', () => {
        video.remove()
    })

    peers[userId] = call
}

function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        video.play()
    })
    videoGrid.append(video)
}

const scrollToBottom = () => {
    let d = $('.main_chat_window')
    d.scrollTop(d.prop("scrollHeight"));
}

const muteUnmute = () => {
    const enabled = myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled;
    if (enabled) {
        myVideoStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
        setUnmuteButton();
    } else {
        setMuteButton();
    }
}

function toggleVideo() {
    const videoStream = myVideoStream;
    if (videoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled) {
        setPlayVideo()
        videoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;
        const data = { userId: peer.id, videoEnabled: false };
        socket.emit('toggle-video', data);
    } else {
        setStopVideo();
        videoStream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true;
        const data = { userId: peer.id, videoEnabled: true };
        socket.emit('toggle-video', data);
    }
}

function toggleAudio() {
    if (audio) {
        setUnmuteButton()
        const data = { userId: peer.id, audioEnabled: false };
        socket.emit('toggle-audio', data);
    } else {
        setMuteButton()
        const data = { userId: peer.id, audioEnabled: true };
        socket.emit('toggle-audio', data);
    }
}


const setMuteButton = () => {
    const html = `
      <i class="fas fa-microphone mute"></i>
      <span>Mute</span>
    `
    document.querySelector('.main__mute_button').innerHTML = html;
}

const setUnmuteButton = () => {
    const html = `
      <i class="unmute fas fa-microphone-slash"></i>
      <span>Unmute</span>
    `
    document.querySelector('.main__mute_button').innerHTML = html;
}

const setStopVideo = () => {
    const html = `
      <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
      <span>Stop Video</span>
    `
    document.querySelector('.main__video_button').innerHTML = html;
}

    

const setPlayVideo = () => {
    const html = `
    <i class="stop fas fa-video-slash"></i>
      <span>Play Video</span>
    `
    document.querySelector('.main__video_button').innerHTML = html;
}
```

this is my script.js file

I am currently working on the audio problem but video one is solved.